# How to background Django API with scalability in AWS?

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an API in Django (restframework) actually hosted in a Elastic Beanstalk in single docker container template Web server using LoadBalancer and AutoScale provided by AWS EB.

I want to background API because it deals with many requests hits in the same sec causing many 5xx http errors. After some research I found that Celery can make this work for me using SQS, but I don't know how to develop this scenario (I can run the API with Celery workers locally, but I don't know how to make this on AWS EB or even in a docker-compose).

Should I use Elastic Beanstalk Worker environment and/or docker-compose?
Can I put Django and Celery in a docker-compose and deploy it on EB Web or I need to change environment tier in this case?

What kind of changes I need to make in my actual project (Docker-Django-EBWeb) to background tasks?

Note: I need some configs in container image to integrate past Oracle 11g DB (instant client 11g + cx-Oracle5.3)

Comment: Throw away AWS EB, SQS and other unnecessary things. They don't make things easier. Use ordinary VMs. For example, AWS EC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to solve this issue using beanstalk is to use a Multicontainer instead of the single container.

My Dockerrun.aws.json is something like

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "staticfiles",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/staticfiles"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy-conf",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/proxy/conf.d"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "app-sock",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/tmp/run"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "image": "REPOSITORY_URL",
      "essential": true,
      "memoryReservation": 256,
      "command": [
        "/app/entrypoint-api.sh"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8000,
          "containerPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "staticfiles",
          "containerPath": "/var/app/current/staticfiles"
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "app-sock",
          "containerPath": "/tmp/run/"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "celery",
      "image": "REPOSITORY_URL",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 256,
      "memoryReservation": 128,
      "command": [
        "/app/entrypoint-celery.sh"
      ],
      "links": [
        "api"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx-proxy",
      "image": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "staticfiles",
          "containerPath": "/var/app/current/staticfiles",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
          "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "nginx-proxy-conf",
          "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d"
        },
        {
          "sourceVolume": "app-sock",
          "containerPath": "/tmp/run/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `/app/entrypoint-api.sh` is like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /app

python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --chdir /app project_name.wsgi --bind unix:/tmp/run/project_name.sock
```

And the `/app/entrypoint-celery.sh` is like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /app

celery -A project_name worker -l info
```

I have this running without any issue at all, the downside is that you need to use ECR and push your Docker images there.

I hope this help.

Comment: Changed my dockerrun.aws.json and my environment successfully launched, but I'm having trouble with 5xx errors yet. I'm trying to use/set Gunicorn like you suggest in the entrypoint-api.sh (I was running the API with python manage.py runserver until now). Nginx is really necessary? Because that was not configured in my case

Comment: I'm using Nginx for the static files, I really don't remember another reason.

Did you check the error log to see why the 500?

Comment: Sorry, I was getting 5xx errors because a bad formatation in celery call (forgot space). Launched the environment and worked well without the need of configuring Nginx. Celery is using SQS and Dockerrun.aws.json with image in ECR. Thank you! Your answer was really helpfull!